# New Datastax driver for Tableau is not working

Tags: cassandra, odbc, tableau-api, datastax

trying to run Tableau on top of DSE 4.7. It fails. I can't do something in worksheet or preview the data. Get this error:

"Missing EOF at 'tablename_i_try_to_query' "

What is the right way to fix it?

Comment: Which ODBC driver?  For Cassandra?  For Shark?  For HIve?  For SparkSQL?
And what query?

Comment: Hi, I found it. Suppose that Tableau UI could be smarter a little bit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've resolved it.
When you setup datasource it Tableau, you have to specify cluster, database and table (a.k.a. column family).
I specified CF/table '**tablename_i_try_to_query**' and dragged it to the pane on the right. 
Then I specified database. It didn't work. Tableau generated query without specifying database.
Then I removed table from pane and put it back again. Tableau started to generate correct query with **database.tablename_i_try_to_query**